# Increase/Decrease variable on scroll

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to increase a variable as the user scrolls up, and decrease when the user scrolls down with JavaScript? There is no maximum or minimum value for the variable, and it would be nice to be able to adjust the sensitivity. I have no idea where to begin, thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
There is no scroll bar because the content of the page fits in the screen with nothing extra. Sorry if this caused any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original Answer

**You can use `window.scrollY`.** It's the distance in pixels from the top of the screen, so if you do `-window.scrollY` to get it to *increase* as they scroll up and *decrease* (become more negative) as they scroll down, like you asked for.

If you want to adjust sensitivity, you could divide it by something arbitrary (in this example, `5`):

```
function getAdjustedScroll() {
    const DIVIDE_AMOUNT = 5;
    return -window.scrollY / DIVIDE_AMOUNT;
}
```

## Edit

You can also use the **`wheel` event** to detect wheel movements on a non-scrolling page.

Using a similar example to the original:

```
let scrollAmount = 0;

document.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
    const DIVIDE_AMOUNT = 5;
    scrollAmount += event.deltaY / DIVIDE_AMOUNT;
});
```

Comment: There is no scroll bar because the page fits in the screen with nothing extra, so the distance from the top wouldn't change. Sorry about that

Comment: @ElectroMonkey OK, I’ve edited my answer with a new way of doing this. Please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot! I noticed that the variable actually decreases when scrolling up and increases when scrolling down, but I fixed this by making DIVIDE_AMOUNT negative.

Comment: @ElecroMonkey Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel). This event is fired when you rotate the mousewheel or similar devices as when you do to scroll for example. Here is an example of how to use it:

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test-div");

var amount = 0;
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(ev) {
  amount += ev.deltaY;
  testDiv.textContent = amount;
});
```

```html
<div id="test-div">SCORLL!</div>
```

**Notes:**

- This event is fired even if no actual scrolling happens. If there is no scroll space, the event still fires.
- If you wan to add sensitivity then just multiply `ev.deltaY` with a number that represent the sensitivity: `amount += 0.5 * ev.delta;` for example.

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test-div");

var amount = 0;
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(ev) {
  amount += ev.deltaY;
  testDiv.textContent = 1000 * amount;
});
```

```html
<div id="test-div">SCORLL!</div>
```

- You can prevent the actual scrolling by using `ev.preventDefault()`. The `amount` variable will still change but the scrolling of the page won't occur.

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test-div");

var amount = 0;
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(ev) {
  amount += ev.deltaY;
  testDiv.textContent = amount;
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div id="test-div">SCORLL!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes there is. by use of getBoundingClientRect(); method which has 4 options:- top,left,bottom and right.further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      let scrollValue = window.scrollY;
      let num = $("#num");
      num.html(scrollValue);
    });
  
  });
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
position: fixed;
font-size: 70px;
top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>Scroll to view <span id="num"></span></p>
```

[Check out the example](https://codepen.io/vasudevapitta/pen/oMbbea)